# How to close multiple contentpages in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I developed two ContentPages to let user choose Country and City.
My application starts with Navigation Page:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.InfoViews.OnBoarding());
```

OnBoarding page redirects Country selection page and country selection page redirects city selection page like below:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new LocationSelector(0));
```

I want to return onboarding page after place selection.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to return to the first page in your [navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical) stack

```
Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```